# How does a C++ command with two equal signs work?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, assign, multiple-assignment

I found some code in the program I work with:

```
PWSTR myWchar = NULL;
WCHAR *p = myWchar = new WCHAR[4];
```

How would I read a line with two equal signs?

How is it computed?

**A:**

```
 myWchar  = new WCHAR[4];
 WCHAR *p = myWchar
```

**or B:**

```
 WCHAR *p = myWchar ;
 myWchar  = new WCHAR[4];
```

Comment: I have honestly no idea, what you're talking about.

Comment: It's option A..

Comment: Assignment is evaluated [right-to-left](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Assign operator has [Right-to-left associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `WCHAR *p = myWchar = new WCHAR[4];` is exactly the same as `WCHAR *p = (myWchar = new WCHAR[4]);`. And note that the initialization of variables (like `PWSTR myWchar = NULL;`) is *not* assignment. It's *initialization*.

Comment: It's not a "command" it's a "statement". Using the correct term here helps not only focus us on your question, but informs how C++ works.

Comment: _@user3443063_ there's no thing like a _"command line with two equal signs"_ in your question. You should clarify what you're actually mean please.

Comment: Coding isn't usually about : how can I write the least amount of cde even if you know how it works, just write two lines. your intent is more explicit and It will really help you when you need to debug.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I'm assuming this is a toy case, not intended as some sort of golfing exercise, since the "long" code you'd actually write would take the same number of lines as the OP's "compact" code: `PWSTR myWchar = new WCHAR[4];` followed by `WCHAR *p = myWchar;`

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know, but toy examples have a tendency to still be used ;)

Comment: Useful term: chaining

Comment: Just be aware of some details: e.g. `double a = 1.1; int b; double c = b = a;` the value of `c` will be `1`. I think it's *normally* best to write out longhand.

Comment: This is not a *command* or a *statement*, it's a declaration with an initialization *expression*. Just like `int i = 2 + 4 * 10`.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb well declaration is a derived class from statement

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie expressions are defined in ISO/IEC 14882:2020 chapter 7, statements in chapter 8, and declarations in chapter 9. There is no "derived class of statement" mentioned anywhere in the definition of the C++ programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's option A, exactly equivalent to (with unnecessary parens):

```
WCHAR *p = (myWchar = new WCHAR[4]);
```

If `myWchar` had a custom `operator=` and/or the type of `p` had a custom constructor or cast from `myWchar`'s type to `p`'s type, this could mean `p` and `myWchar` end up slightly different from one another, but in this case, `WCHAR*` and `PWSTR` are fundamentally the same type, so they both end up assigned to the same thing, the result of the `new WCHAR[4]`.

In this case, it's actually the result of assignment to `myWchar` used as the initialization for `p`, but even if the structure was:

```
PWSTR myWchar = NULL;
WCHAR *p;
p = myWchar = new WCHAR[4];
```

so it was all assignment, no initialization, [assignment is right-to-left associative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so it would occur in the same order (it just would use assignment rather than initialization semantics for the assignment to `p`, which could matter for custom types).

Comment: Knowing this site, this will be closed and deleted as it's a duplicate. (All C++ questions are a duplicate of "can you give me the C++ specification.") But it's a good answer. Have an upvote, and enjoy it whilst you can.